# How many gods/goddesses are there in total in greek mythology?

Tags: greek

If there was a diagram with every god in it, that would be cool, but I doubt you can find that, so a number will do I guess.

How many gods/goddesses are there in total in greek mythology?

Comment: Approximately equivalent to the number of angels who can dance on the head of a pin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A lot.

[Theoi](http://www.theoi.com/Tree0Latin.html) has a nice family tree-

[image: fam tree]

And so you count, and get a total of...

## 3142 gods/godesses

If you count the Potami, Naiads, and Astriaos as 1 god/goddess, and including Titans as gods.

Comment: holy zeus that's a lot

Comment: Since when is Eris not the offspring of Zeus and Hera? Also missing the [hekatonkhires]:http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hekatonkheires

Comment: @bleh props for "brute forcing' that number.